# Reading blocks from text file into 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

This has been killing me all day/night and I cannot seem to come up with a solution. Basically, I have a text file containing a 2D vector (generated from a C++ program) in doubles. I need to read this into a 2D array in Python so I can plot a spectrogram. Here is what the data looks like:

```
-18.2258 -18.3581 -18.7323 -19.2183 -19.8016 -20.6132 -21.8101 -22.5386 -21.8071    
-20.9063 -20.4136 -20.3022 -20.3428 -20.4091 -20.6703 -21.0293 -21.5167 -22.1915    
-23.0438 -23.9086 -24.5955 -26.2508 -26.0188 -22.2163 -19.933 -18.6816 -18.1048
-18.0222 18.3233 -19.0456 -20.3134 -22.7954 -25.8716 -21.4845 -19.1923 -17.9268 
-17.4657 -17.3888 -16.9999 -16.4006 -15.9175 -15.8319 -16.1705 -16.6967 -17.0734 


-7.92685 -10.8266 -16.392 -12.4901 -13.0831 -17.7215 -17.5159 -14.1485 -12.9897 -12.0444   
-11.8363 -12.6952 -12.9652 -14.3788 -13.8465 -17.529 -17.4747 -11.9521 -12.545 -13.8976 
-12.4176 -15.3273 -14.8081 -19.4117 -17.9596 -16.2607 -16.7505 -15.8918 -16.5602 
-17.2225 -16.9048 -15.1381 -17.37 -16.43 -14.9437 -14.9821
```

Each block of data is separated by 2 lines within the text file.

I have tried the following:

```
with open('spec.txt') as file:
    array2d = [[float(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in file]
```

However, this does not work and I just seem to be getting a lot of arrays generated.

Anyone have any ideas to solve this?

P.S. each block is of the same size. However, to shorten this question, I just included a sample.

Comment: What are you using to plot?  And what exactly do you mean by '2d array'?  A list of lists?  Or a `numpy` array?

Comment: @hpaulj Hey, I'm using matplotlib to plot.. I've tried Ashwini Chaudhary implementation, but, it doesn't work. The results are kind of messed up

Comment: It would easier to test if your second block had the same number of numbers as the first.  That way the resulting list of lists can be fed directly to `numpy.array` to create a 2d array.

Comment: This data file would be easier to load if it was written with one block per line.  Then `np.loadtxt(filename)` would be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
raw_text = """-18.2258 -18.3581 -18.7323 -19.2183 -19.8016 -20.6132 -21.8101 -22.5386 -21.8071    
-20.9063 -20.4136 -20.3022 -20.3428 -20.4091 -20.6703 -21.0293 -21.5167 -22.1915    
-23.0438 -23.9086 -24.5955 -26.2508 -26.0188 -22.2163 -19.933 -18.6816 -18.1048
-18.0222 18.3233 -19.0456 -20.3134 -22.7954 -25.8716 -21.4845 -19.1923 -17.9268 
-17.4657 -17.3888 -16.9999 -16.4006 -15.9175 -15.8319 -16.1705 -16.6967 -17.0734 


-7.92685 -10.8266 -16.392 -12.4901 -13.0831 -17.7215 -17.5159 -14.1485 -12.9897 -12.0444   
-11.8363 -12.6952 -12.9652 -14.3788 -13.8465 -17.529 -17.4747 -11.9521 -12.545 -13.8976 
-12.4176 -15.3273 -14.8081 -19.4117 -17.9596 -16.2607 -16.7505 -15.8918 -16.5602 
-17.2225 -16.9048 -15.1381 -17.37 -16.43 -14.9437 -14.9821"""
#in your example raw_text = open(some_file).read()
blocks = raw_text.split("\n\n\n")
split_blicks = [[float(v) for v in block.split()] for block in blocks]
```

is that what you want?

Comment: what ? no see the comment line

Answer (score 0):

Split the data at empty lines:

```
def split_at_empty_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        arr = []
        for line in f:
            #If the line is empty and arr is not empty, means it's
            #time to return the collected items and set `arr` back to [].
            if not line.strip() and arr:
                yield arr
                arr = []
            #If the line is not empty then simply collect the items in `arr`
            elif line.strip(): 
                arr.extend(float(x) for x in line.split())
            #Ignore the case of empty line and empty `arr`

        #Check if arr is not empty or not, if not empty returns its content.
        if arr: yield arr
...         
>>> list(split_at_empty_lines('abc1.txt'))
[
 [-18.2258, -18.3581, -18.7323, -19.2183, -19.8016, -20.6132, -21.8101, -22.5386, -21.8071, -20.9063, -20.4136, -20.3022, -20.3428, -20.4091, -20.6703, -21.0293, -21.5167, -22.1915, -23.0438, -23.9086, -24.5955, -26.2508, -26.0188, -22.2163, -19.933, -18.6816, -18.1048, -18.0222, 18.3233, -19.0456, -20.3134, -22.7954, -25.8716, -21.4845, -19.1923, -17.9268, -17.4657, -17.3888, -16.9999, -16.4006, -15.9175, -15.8319, -16.1705, -16.6967, -17.0734],
 [-7.92685, -10.8266, -16.392, -12.4901, -13.0831, -17.7215, -17.5159, -14.1485, -12.9897, -12.0444, -11.8363, -12.6952, -12.9652, -14.3788, -13.8465, -17.529, -17.4747, -11.9521, -12.545, -13.8976, -12.4176, -15.3273, -14.8081, -19.4117, -17.9596, -16.2607, -16.7505, -15.8918, -16.5602, -17.2225, -16.9048, -15.1381, -17.37, -16.43, -14.9437, -14.9821]
]
```

Comment: Thanks! But how could I store the result of this method inside another array so it can be plotted?

Comment: @user1326876 I don't understand, simply call `list()` on it(as shown in code) and you'll get a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce it quite a bit with list comprehensions.

```
with open('myfile') as f:
   return ([float(x) for x in l.split() if l] for l in (raw.strip() for raw in f))
```

Note the outer parens makes this return a generator rather than processing the entire file before returning anything.